# CSS area of 2 divs intersections be transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am making a website and the background is a blue gradient there is a div which is white, there is another smaller div above the white one. I want the smaller div above to be transparent so its kind of like a "window" through the white div so you can see the background gradient behind.

For context I want to do this as I am going to make a white circle and a burger menu icon above which is transparent through the circle to the background gradient.

Sorry if that was a bit confusing i have a diagram. Any help is much appreciated thanks.

[image: Diagram]

## **My Current Code:**

#### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anonymous+Pro&family=Lato&family=Ubuntu+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script src="./app.js" defer></script>
    <title>lBark</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="burger-menu">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu-bar"></div>
        <div class="menu-bar"></div>
        <div class="menu-bar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <button style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; width: 10vw; height: 10vh; cursor: none;" onclick="alert('hello')"></button> -->
    <img id="cursor" style="opacity: 0;" src="./img/Cursor.svg">
    <div style="width: 5vw; height: 10vh; background-color: red; position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0;"></div>
    <div style="width: 5vw; height: 10vh; background-color: green; position: absolute; left: 5vw; bottom: 0;"></div>
    <div style="width: 5vw; height: 10vh; background-color: blue; position: absolute; left: 10vw; bottom: 0;"></div>
    <p class="hero">Epicness</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### style.css:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: transparent;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* cursor: none; */
  background: linear-gradient(
    135deg,
    rgba(95, 21, 242, 1) 0%,
    rgba(28, 127, 238, 1) 25%,
    rgba(47, 201, 226, 1) 50%,
    rgba(63, 218, 216, 1) 75%,
    rgba(79, 220, 74, 1) 100%
  );
}

#cursor {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background-color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 3rem;
  height: auto;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 0.3s, width ease-in-out 0.1s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hero {
  font-size: 15rem;
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#burger-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 12vw;
  height: 12vw;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#burger-menu .circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* background: radial-gradient(circle at center, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 30%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%); */
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(40%, -40%);
}

#burger-menu .menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 16%;
}

#burger-menu .menu-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  background-color: black;
}
```

#### app.js:

```
// Variables {{{
let dotPositions = [];
let cursorX = 0;
let cursorY = 0;
// }}}

// Cursor Control {{{
{
  const cursor = document.querySelector("#cursor");
  let firstCursorMove = true;

  document.onmousemove = (event) => {
    if (firstCursorMove) {
      firstCursorMove = false;
      cursor.style.opacity = 1;
      event
    }

    cursorX = event.clientX;
    cursorY = event.clientY;

    cursor.style.left = cursorX + "px";
    cursor.style.top = cursorY + "px";
  };

  // document.onmousedown = () => {
  //   if (!firstCursorMove)
  //   {
  //     expandingDot();
  //   }
  // }

  document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
      cursor.style.width = "5rem";
    });

    button.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      cursor.style.width = "";
    });
  })
}
// }}}

// Background {{{
{
  // const canvas = document.querySelector("#background-canvas");
  // const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  // // Depending on distance from top left decrease dot size
  // // When scrolling dots move towards top left and change size
  // // When link clicked black dot at link which expands
  // // Splash effect on click
  // canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  // canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  function expandingDot() {
    let expandingCircle = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(expandingCircle);
    expandingCircle.style.cssText = `position: absolute; left: ${cursorX}px; top: ${cursorY}px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0); border-radius: 50%; background-color: black; transition: transform 1s ease-in-out; will-change: transform;`;

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
        expandingCircle.style.width = "250vh";
        expandingCircle.style.height = "250vh";
      }
  
      else {
        expandingCircle.style.width = "250vw";
        expandingCircle.style.height = "250vw";
      }

      expandingCircle.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)";
    }, 0);
  }
}

function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
// }}}
```

#### Cursor.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 20 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;">
    <path d="M10,0C15.519,0 20,4.481 20,10C20,15.519 15.519,20 10,20C4.481,20 0,15.519 0,10C0,4.481 4.481,0 10,0ZM10,5C12.76,5 15,7.24 15,10C15,12.76 12.76,15 10,15C7.24,15 5,12.76 5,10C5,7.24 7.24,5 10,5Z" style="fill:white;"/>
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="3" style="fill:white;"/>
</svg>
```

In the code I provided I would like the menu bars to instead be black but be see through to the bodys background which is a gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this with a [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) but you might consider just using an SVG for the entire circle with the hole in it rather than masking a div.

```css
.container {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, aliceblue 0, skyblue 20px);
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.clipped {
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: url(#mask);
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="mask">
      <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M 0 0 h 100 v 100 h -100 v -100 l 25 25 h 50 v 50 h -50 v -50" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="container">
  <div class="clipped"><div>
</div>
```